# UserDefaults in a UITableViewCell not saving (swift3)

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell, nsuserdefaults

My code right now just lists things you manually enter. However when the user switches view controllers the code disappears. I tried to use userdefualts to save my current code in the number of rows in selection function but it does not save the items in the tableview cells. I just want to save whatever is in the tableview cells.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

var items: [String] = [""]


@IBOutlet weak var listTableView: UITableView!
@IBAction func addItem(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    alert()
}

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    listTableView.dataSource = self



}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "listitem") as! ItemTableViewCell
    cell.itemLabel.text = items[indexPath.row]

    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero




    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    userDefaults.setValue(items, forKey: "items")
    userDefaults.synchronize()
    return items.count



}
func alert(){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addTextField{
        (textfield) in
        textfield.placeholder = " Enter "

    }
    let add = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default){
        (action) in
        let textfield = alert.textFields![0] 

        self.items.append(textfield.text!)

        self.listTableView.reloadData()
    }
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) {
        (alert) in


    }
    alert.addAction(add)
    alert.addAction(cancel)

    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)


}}
```

Comment: What does `when the user switches view controllers the code disappears` mean? Is `numberOfRowsInSection` ever called?

Comment: What is the type of `items`? If it is a custom object, you can't just store them in `UserDefaults`.

Comment: @Ryan When the user goes to the home page then to the list page. All of the stuff written on the list page is gone when the return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of issues in your code:

1. You never load your data back from `UserDefaults`.  - This is the big one
2. There is no need to call `synchronise`.
3. You should save your data when data is added/deleted, not in `numberOfRowsInSection`.
4. It will look nicer if you insert a new row rather than reloading the whole table

I would suggest something like:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    var items = [String]()

    @IBOutlet weak var listTableView: UITableView!
    @IBAction func addItem(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        alert()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        listTableView.dataSource = self

        self.items = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey:"items")  ?? [String]()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "listitem") as! ItemTableViewCell
        cell.itemLabel.text = items[indexPath.row]

        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count    
    }

    func saveData() {
        userDefaults.standard.set(items, forKey: "items")
    }

    func alert(){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField{
            (textfield) in
            textfield.placeholder = " Enter "

        }
        let add = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default){
            (action) in
            guard let textfield = alert.textFields?.first else {
                return
            }

            if let newText= textfield.text {
                self.items.append(newText)
                saveData()
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: items.count - 1, section: 0)
                self.listTableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            }
        }

        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) {
            (alert) in

        }

        alert.addAction(add)
        alert.addAction(cancel)

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        saveData()

    }
}
```

Also, you shouldn't really use `UserDefaults` for data storage this way, but I presume this is just a simple learning exercise.

Comment: self.items = items = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey:"items") as? [String] ?? [String]() is not compiling

Comment: Sorry, it was typo.  Fixed.

Comment: Please consider using the designated methods for setting [set(_:forKey:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414067-set) and getting [stringArray(forKey:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1416414-stringarray). Don't suggest KVC for UserDefaults.